# Correctly set meta description

Tags: meta-tags, google-search

I am having an issue with the meta tag *description* in my personal web site, when using it like that:

```
<meta name="description" content="my content" />
```

A search in Google for my homepage doesn't display the description I set but some contents of my page.
I read articles about that but I can't figure it out why this is happening.

According to google support, here is a good way to define a description of your site:

```
<meta name="Description" content="Author: A.N. Author, 
Illustrator: P. Picture, Category: Books, Price: $17.99, 
Length: 784 pages">
```

Is this meta content description going to be a standard ? Some kind of formated object ?

Or maybe this is my XHTML way to write tag the problem ?

Comment: I don't think google uses the description for that purpose anymore... looking for the article i read that suggested it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google announced a while back that it wouldn't use meta descriptions for ranking.

The meta description *is* sometimes used as the summary text in search results, but if Google thinks it has found a better summary on your page based on the user's search, it will use that instead.

> In some situations this description is used as a part of the snippet shown in the search results

Your meta description should really match up to the page content very well, otherwise it definitely won't be shown. The example you have shown contains *structured data* - but there is no indication that there is a strong preference for this (i.e. it may not be relevant to all pages).

As always, the algorithms are mysterious and subject to change.